# How to adjust Django query set value?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a view:

```
def get_comment_tree(request):
    news_id = request.GET.get("news_id")
    ret = list(Comment.objects.filter(news_id=news_id).values("nid", "content", "parent_comment_id", "user", "create_time"))
    return JsonResponse(ret, safe=False)
```

The return of the view will be sent back to ajax.Now problems are,how can I convert the value **"user" to "username"**,now I only get the user_id and the **"create_time" to naturalday or naturaltime format**.

If I use python to convert these data I think it would be a little complicated,any friend can help?

This is my comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    """

    评论表

    """
    nid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    news = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name='评论文章', to='News',to_field='id',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name='评论者', to='User',to_field='id',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(verbose_name='评论内容', max_length=255)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='创建时间', auto_now_add=True)
    parent_comment = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
from django.db.models import F

Comment.objects.filter(news_id=news_id).values("nid", "content", "parent_comment_id", "create_time", username=F('user__username'))
```

Comment: The return data still only shows the id not the the username,can you help?

Comment: Still only return the id.But thank you very much!

Comment: yes,sure,this filed is a default one ,my user model inheritance AbstractUser,and I checked  it in mysql,there is a username filed.

Comment: Works now!Can you help me so?lve the time issue?I mean convert the 'create_time' to naturalday or naturaltime format?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229310/discussion-between-sumithran-and-william).

Comment: This is how it works in your solution,I changed the comment model user filed to:    user = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name='评论者', to='User',to_field='id',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Answer (score 0):

If user is foreign key relation with [models.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/) , then you can access username as user.username.

And for create_time , it depends on the datatype you have configured for it in models.py file.
If it is datetime object then you can convert it into string using [datetime.strftime()](https://strftime.org/) as `create_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but this is not working!

Answer (score 0):

if in Comment model user is ForeignKey, you can `use user__username` to get the value, if you whant to change user__username to user, you can try this:

```
list(Comment.objects.filter(news_id=news_id).values("nid", "content", "parent_comment_id", user='user__name', "create_time"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but this is not working!

Answer (score 0):

```
ret = list(Comment.objects.filter(news_id=news_id).values("nid", "content", "parent_comment_id", "user__username", "create_time"))
```

This query will show username with key as user__username.

Comment: I tried this way but the username still not showing, it says undefined.

Comment: check user table using django admin if that particular user is there or not .